# Make a sentence with the most different uses of the same word

Tags: english, language, open-ended

### Background

I recently stumbled across the following grammatically correct sentence:

> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo.

This sentence relies on the fact that the word buffalo could be multiple things, and that each of these is used as a different part of speech, namely:

- A city in New York (used as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).
- The American Bison (used as a [noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun)).
- A [verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb) meaning to intimidate of confuse.

The sentence roughly translates to: "Bison from Buffalo, which other bison from Buffalo intimidate, intimidate bison from Buffalo."

There's also a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) for this sentence, which explains things more in depth than I do here. On a side note, it has my new favorite title for a Wikipedia article.

### Challenge

With that background, the goal of this question is to **create a sentence made up of the *most* different homonyms of the same word.** This is *not* a challenge to find the longest sentence consisting of one word. The "buffalo" sentence above has eight words, but only uses three definitions. And, as Deusovi pointed out on [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33704/39637) somewhat similar question, a sentence using just the word buffalo could be made arbitrarily large.

I know this changes the scope of the original question, but hopefully previous answers can still be used to help form new answers.

### Notes

While the buffalo sentence is nice in that all words used in it are spelled the same way, I will allow a mix of singular and plural variations of the word. I would also like a link or formal definition for each different use of the word, to ensure that each use is in fact an actual, even if narrow, use.

Comment: I actually found this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/what-word-can-fulfill-the-most-parts-of-speech , does this answer your question?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel The answer there probably works. However, there are several questions on English SE that have very similar questions on Puzzling, so I think I'll leave this for now, just because Puzzling is a *bit* less constrained to the rules of grammar and might come up with a more creative answer than the ones there. Also, that question is several years old, and there may be words that have changed more recently (see note about words being verbed).

Comment: ... but is this *really* a puzzle?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with [Puzzling site scope](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): it is not connected to understanding, creating, analysing, or solving puzzles. It might be tangentially separately related to those topics, but that puzzles may feature bicycle pumps would not make bicycle pumps on topic to ask about either. Even in in the phrase given there are only three different usages, and "most" as a superlative isn't necessary to construct another such phrase.

Comment: If this does remain on topic, can we please categorically exclude expletives? The F-word and others already virtually have the most diverse meanings (due to sort of having no one meaning at all), but I don't think we'd be pursuing making such a phrase out of expletives.

Comment: Why the heck would you exclude a whole category of words with the "most diverse meanings" when this is basically exactly what the OP asked for?

Comment: @Rubio We could argue about that as a philosophical question, but certainly language optimisation questions like this have been on-topic at Puzzling SE since 2014: [see here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended+language) for examples.

Comment: @doppelgreener Language optimisation questions are certainly on-topic for Puzzling. The only potential issue with this question might be that it's not clearly enough defined (what exactly is a "part of speech", for example? OP, feel free to [edit] to add details and conditions), but really I think it's clear enough and have voted to reopen.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I didn’t vote to close, but I don’t think this belongs here. It’s going to get bogged down in how to define parts of speech, something that was a challenge even on English.SE in the similar question linked earlier in the comments. The central element of picking the best answer is going to be in deciding which submission actually is comprised of a set of strict homonyms that cover the largest number of distinct parts of speech-including figuring out what parts of speech each usage actually is, and if they overlap.  To me, that makes it a language question, not a puzzle.

Comment: @Guest On the basis that Stack Exchange tries to avoid unnecessary expletives, so a question that becomes about competing to find out how diversely (or creatively) we can use expletives would probably be a poor fit for the network.

Comment: @doppelgreener, I take a different view of it. I suspect the asker didn't consider the possibility that an expletive might be the best answer to the question. I also suspect that an expletive *is* likely the best answer to the question. So the expletive is not unnecessary if that's true, because it is the best answer (through no fault of the asker). Restricting the use of expletives when they might well be the best possible answer seems like an even *worse* fit for a QA network.

Comment: @Guest I actually completely agree with you. I think an expletive would indeed be the best answer to the question - and the second through sixth best answers and then some. People competing to generate the most diverse demonstration of vulgarities is something categorically unsuitable for this network. Why not shift those out of the way as foregone conclusion to explore *anything else?* Further, what help will that be to anyone? Someone inclined to make a *Buffalo buffalo* or *shi shi shi* out of f-words hardly needs our guidance and prompting.

Comment: @doppelgreener, to be honest I'm *very* inclined to do it with f-words. I don't know what help it would be, but it sounds like fun. In all seriousness, though, I don't think you'd *ever* want to just "shift [the best answers] out of the way as a foregone conclusion" in a QA-type format. I mean, if there are a bunch of toddlers around who can't handle f-words, that's one thing, but it looks to me like users of this site are grown enough to handle it. I guess if it's a real concern this conversation should be had on meta, though.

Comment: @Guest Sure! Be my guest. Go ahead and do that. [But Stack Exchange sites do not in general permit vulgarities unless they are unavoidable.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/152515) They can be avoided here, so they should be, and we should absolutely avoid a scenario where we are, in fact, specifically incentivising using as many of them as possible in as many varied ways as possible.

Comment: @Rubio, I see what you mean about parts of speech being vague. I struggled with that a bit while writing my answer. I think there can be clues in the question, though. For example it's interesting that "buffalo" is the plural of "buffalo." The word I chose doesn't have this property, but it does seem to work as both a countable and an uncountable noun, giving sort of the same effect. So for example it might be appropriate to list both usage examples (countable and uncountable) in this case, and show how that can give a wide variety of potential meanings to a long sentence composed of that word

Comment: NSFW: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQTZVPWq3EQ

Answer (score 10):

How about..

> Shit.

**Noun, uncountable:**

> Look at this shit.

**Noun, countable: ***

> Who gives a shit?

**Intransitive verb:**

> I gotta shit.

**Transitive verb:**

> Come on, don't shit me.

**Proper article:**

> Shit just got real.

**Pronoun:**

> Little shit took my sandwich.

**Quantifier pronoun (slang, US):**

> The word "shit" has shit tons of meanings.

**Conjunctive Adverb:**

> I come here most days; shit, maybe every day.

**Adverb (slang, UK):**

> This engine runs a bit shit.

**Adjective (slang, UK):**

> That's a shit song.

And of course **Interjection**:

> Shit!

<sub>* I'm aware that nouns are generally either countable or uncountable, but it seems this one can be used either way. This gives us flexibility similar to what we get from "buffalo" being the plural of singular "buffalo."</sub>

Comment: You could say the same of a certain four-letter word beginning with F. In fact, in English class at school we saw a short film to that effect. It was very entertaining.

Comment: @F1Krazy, now that you mention it, I'm sure there was a post like that on one of the English SE sites a few years back...

Comment: Yeah, the s-word's got f*** all on the f-word, except that the latter takes on the "ing" suffix in many of its roles.

Comment: Now I'm tempted to try f- without f-ing it up with suffixes.

Comment: NSFW:  [How to use the word 'F*#^'](http://bit.ly/2BgNPt6) <- bitly coz there's swears in the link too.

Comment: @F1Krazy Are talking about [OSHO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQTZVPWq3EQ)? That dude is crazy.

Answer (score 1):

We can argue if this counts as English or not, but

> Fit fit fits fit fit?

is a Doric phrase meaning "Which foot fits which shoe?"

It's not as long as the Buffalo one, but if we accept accents and dialects alongside dictionary English it opens up a lot more areas where we might find something longer than it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/what-word-can-fulfill-the-most-parts-of-speech) which cointain multiple words that answers your question, but I thought of another word, with four uses:

> The word **Fine**

It can be:

> Adjective: "this was a fine piece of filmmaking" 
>  Adverb: "And how's the job-hunting going? Oh, fine."
>  Noun: "a parking fine"
>  Verb: "he was fined $600 and sentenced to one day in jail"