# How many of the same word can you fit consecutively into a single English sentence?

Tags: word-sequence

I'm looking for sentences that contain a sequence of at least two identically-written words in a row, such as the following:  "I like that that car is red."

The challenge is to make as long such a sequence as you can.

There are some restrictions, though:

1. The sentence must be grammatically correct.
2. The words in the sequence must not be assigned made-up or extremely uncommon meanings--in the above sentence, I might have done this by claiming that my friends and I call cars "thats",  and had three "that"s in a row.
3. The sentence must not be redundant or cyclic--that is, it cannot have a pattern of "A-refers-to-B-refers-to-A-refers-to-B...", or something similar.

The sentence need not be useful in regular writing or speech, but the more sense it makes, the more interesting it is.

Please include your sentence's "score" (the number of identical words in the sequence), and, if you'd like, an explanation of how it should be understood.

I've come up with one that I think has the longest sequence possible in it, and another that might be used in regular writing, but is still very long. I'll add those once I learn how to use the "spoiler" bars, but for now I'd just like to see what others can come up with. :)

Edit: I'm not looking specifically for sentences that consist only of a single word repeated some number of times, but ones that include some number of consecutive repetitions of a single word.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: Possible duplicate of [longest sentence using only one word and variants](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33701/longest-sentence-using-only-one-word-and-variants)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is the exact type of [open-ended question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) that is disallowed on Puzzling: there's no clear right answer, and any answer can potentially be outdone. Additionally, there is a lot of ambiguity over what counts as a grammatically correct sentence. For these reasons, it's not a *puzzle* in the sense that we use it here on Puzzling, and so it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I apologize; I didn't read through the rules before posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this falls under your rule about being cyclic, but you could start with a sentence like

> "Saying "Saying" is pleasurable."

And then do this:

> "Saying "Saying "Saying" is pleasurable" is pleasurable".

And finally

> repeat this as many times as desired. The score is unbounded. I'm guessing this violates your rule, but it isn't redundant because the final statement has a unique meaning that none of the sub-statements express. It also isn't "cyclical" in the way you defined. I would say that it is "recursive" and I'm guessing that was what you were getting at.